# OPS4j repository alternative

Tags: java, osgi, maven

The OPS4J repository is down at present and I am trying to run pax-provision using a profile for spring-dm. My question is how do I tell maven to locate the profile information from a site other than ops4j.org.

Is this possible? ideally I would like to cache all the packages from the repo especially the spring-dm details which seem never to be cached and are downloaded all the time making coding on the train and times when the site is down impossible.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your configurations with [Pax Runner Platform Extender](http://paxrunner.ops4j.org/display/paxrunner/5.4.1.+Pax+Runner+-+Platform+-+Extender#5.4.1.PaxRunner-Platform-Extender-configuraton). Just create xml with platform (system bundle and other bundles definition) and attach it to Pax runned with `org.ops4j.pax.runner.platform.definitionURL` property.

You can find current Equinox/Felix/Knopflerfish platforms definitions 
 https://scm.ops4j.org/repos/ops4j/qa/pax/runner-1.4.0  (see `pax-runner-platform-[platform.name]/src/main/resources/META-INF/platform-[platform.name]`)

With these configurations you are mo flexible, because you can use the last versions of frameworks and libraries/bundles that are not supported by PaxRunner 1.4.0